# Reverse sort of matrix using numpy based on a specific column

Tags: python, sorting, numpy, matrix

```
import numpy as np

mat = np.array([[1,21,3],[5,4,2],[56,12,4]])
mat_sort = mat[mat[:,2].argsort()]
print(mat_sort)
```

Output:

```
[[ 5  4  2]
 [56 12  4]
 [ 1 21  3]]
```

If I wish to get the  reverse sorting based on any column, say 3rd, what changes do i make to the code? Meaning, I wish to get:

```
[[56 12  4]
[ 1 21  3]
[ 5  4  2]]
```

P.s Yes I understand this is an easy question but I couldn't find an answer that I understood and was based for matrix and not an array or vector. TIA :)

Comment: Addendum: By reverse I mean decreasing order.

Comment: So in your case, `mat[mat[:, 2].argsort()[::-1]` would work.

Comment: or `mat[-mat[:,2].argsort()]`.

Comment: @miradulo okay thanks. Both of them work. I have a question when using 'mat[mat[:, 2].argsort()[::-1]' what does the ::  signify  in [::-1]? why can't i write just [-1]?

Comment: @user10089194 No worries. The [Indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html) section of the NumPy docs has all the details about indexing in NumPy, but it is just extending the basic Python slice notation, which has the notation `[<first to include>:<first to exclude>:<step>]`. So with `[::-1]`, you're including all elements of the array and stepping backwards through it.

Comment: Ahh thanks man. Understood clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Just reverse the `argsort` indices:

```
mat_sort = mat[mat[:, 2].argsort()[::-1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print(mat_sort[::-1]) #just print in reverse
```